# C#- ASP.NET ViewModel have null reference but have values

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with render View with Razor. I have a interesting warnings :

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_q1mgjijg.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

And the same with different libraries App_Web_qpwhgwuw.dll , App_Web_index.cshtml.e59e9c51.8k5fyp3z.dll , App_Web_2unx2e1e.dll or App_Web_xf32dsyo.dll I really don't know whats going on.

my controller:

```
   public ActionResult Index(CandidatesAndPartyViewModel vm)
    {
        vm = new CandidatesAndPartyViewModel
        {
            Candidates = _repositoryCandidates.Candidates,
            PoliticalParties = _repositoryPoliticalParty.PoliticalParties,
            TypesOfElections = _repositoryTypeOfElection.TypeOfElections,
            
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

And retrun correct filled model.

My View:

```
   @foreach (var election in Model.TypesOfElections)
    {
        <div id="@election.Id">
            @foreach (var politicalParty in Model.PoliticalParties.OrderBy(x => x.NameOfPoliticalParty))
            {

                <div id="@politicalParty.NameOfPoliticalParty.Replace(" ", "-").Replace("'", "-")" class="section scrollspy">
                    <p class="nameOfParty">@politicalParty.NameOfPoliticalParty</p>
                    <div class="nameOfCandidats">

                        @foreach (var candidate in Model.Candidates.Where(x => x.PoliticalParty.Id == politicalParty.Id &&
                                x.TypeOfElections.NameOfElection == election.NameOfElection))
                            {
                            <p>
                               @candidate
                            </p>
                            }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
```

The error line is :

```
 x => x.PoliticalParty.Id == politicalParty.Id &&
      x.TypeOfElections.NameOfElection == election.NameOfElection)
```

I try to display whitout that line and view works correctly, but need this line :(
Thanks !

Comment: Grab a debugger and check what's happening? But the error is clear and you have to check your objects.

Comment: display error when try to display a value. I check it few times and my objects are correct filled. Now I noticed that the other views also have the same error and worked previously

Comment: One of these is null: `Model.Candidates`, `x.PoliticalParty`, `politicalParty`, `x.TypeOfElections`, `election`.  You'd need to inspect them in the debugger or add null-checking code to know for sure which one.

Comment: Candidates: http://prntscr.com/dtec9r ,  PoliticalParty: http://prntscr.com/dtecm1 , TypeOfElection : http://prntscr.com/dtecty  Everything I want to display is in object.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that `x.TypeOfElections` is null. As to why, there's not enough visibility into your entity classes to say. In general, if you need to access a member of a property that could be null, you should do a null-check first, here the easiest method would be to add a condition:

```
x.TypeOfElections != null && x.TypeOfElections.NameOfElection == election.NameOfElection
```

I can hazard a guess at why this might be null, but again, without your entity classes, it's impossible to say for sure. More likely than not, you have neglected the `virtual` keyword on the property. Entity Framework automatically loads related entities by overriding the property to add its lazy-loading logic. If the property is not virtual, it cannot override, and hence, it cannot load the relationship.

Comment: I have Fluent Nhibernete database, and have "virtual " in properties. Here is my debug from view : http://prntscr.com/dtekm8 I use your method and still the same error.